# KStream-KTable join writing to the KTable: How to sync the join with the ktable write?

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

I'm having some issue with how the following topology behaves:

```java
String topic = config.topic();

KTable<UUID, MyData> myTable = topology.builder().table(UUIDSerdes.get(), GsonSerdes.get(MyData.class), topic);

// Receive a stream of various events
topology.eventsStream()
    // Only process events that are implementing MyEvent
    .filter((k, v) -> v instanceof MyEvent)
    // Cast to ease the code
    .mapValues(v -> (MyEvent) v)
    // rekey by data id
    .selectKey((k, v) -> v.data.id)
    .peek((k, v) -> L.info("Event:"+v.action))
    // join the event with the according entry in the KTable and apply the state mutation
    .leftJoin(myTable, eventHandler::handleEvent, UUIDSerdes.get(), EventSerdes.get())
    .peek((k, v) -> L.info("Updated:" + v.id + "-" + v.id2))
    // write the updated state to the KTable.
    .to(UUIDSerdes.get(), GsonSerdes.get(MyData.class), topic);
```

My Issue happens when i receive different events at the same time. As my state mutation is done by the `leftJoin` and then written by the `to` method. I can have the following occuring if event 1 and 2 are received at the same time with the same key:

```
event1 joins with state A => state A mutated to state X
event2 joins with state A => state A mutated to state Y
state X written to the KTable topic
state Y written to the KTable topic
```

Because of that, state Y doesn't have the changes from `event1`, so I lost data.

Here's in terms of logs what I see (the `Processing:...` part is logged from inside the value joiner):

```
Event:Event1
Event:Event2
Processing:Event1, State:none
Updated:1-null
Processing:Event2, State:none
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Event2 event received but we don't have data for id 1
```

`Event1` can be considered as the creation event: it will create the entry in the KTable so it doesn't matter if the state is empty. `Event2` though needs to apply it's changes to an existing state but it doesn't find any because the first state mutation still hasn't been written to the KTable (it's still hasn't been processed by the `to` method)

**Is there anyway to make sure that my leftJoin and my writes into the ktable are done atomically ?**

Thanks

**Update & current solution**

Thanks to the response of @Matthias I was able to find a solution using a `Transformer`.

Here's what the code looks like:

That's the transformer

```java
public class KStreamStateLeftJoin<K, V1, V2> implements Transformer<K, V1, KeyValue<K, V2>> {

    private final String                    stateName;
    private final ValueJoiner<V1, V2, V2>   joiner;
    private final boolean                   updateState;

    private KeyValueStore<K, V2>            state;

    public KStreamStateLeftJoin(String stateName, ValueJoiner<V1, V2, V2> joiner, boolean updateState) {
        this.stateName = stateName;
        this.joiner = joiner;
        this.updateState = updateState;
    }

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void init(ProcessorContext context) {
        this.state = (KeyValueStore<K, V2>) context.getStateStore(stateName);
    }

    @Override
    public KeyValue<K, V2> transform(K key, V1 value) {
        V2 stateValue = this.state.get(key); // Get current state
        V2 updatedValue = joiner.apply(value, stateValue); // Apply join
        if (updateState) {
            this.state.put(key, updatedValue); // write new state
        }
        return new KeyValue<>(key, updatedValue);
    }

    @Override
    public KeyValue<K, V2> punctuate(long timestamp) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {}
}
```

And here's the adapted topology:

```java
String topic = config.topic();
String store = topic + "-store";

KTable<UUID, MyData> myTable = topology.builder().table(UUIDSerdes.get(), GsonSerdes.get(MyData.class), topic, store);

// Receive a stream of various events
topology.eventsStream()
    // Only process events that are implementing MyEvent
    .filter((k, v) -> v instanceof MyEvent)
    // Cast to ease the code
    .mapValues(v -> (MyEvent) v)
    // rekey by data id
    .selectKey((k, v) -> v.data.id)
    // join the event with the according entry in the KTable and apply the state mutation
    .transform(() -> new KStreamStateLeftJoin<UUID, MyEvent, MyData>(store, eventHandler::handleEvent, true), store)
    // write the updated state to the KTable.
    .to(UUIDSerdes.get(), GsonSerdes.get(MyData.class), topic);
```

As we're using the KTable's KV StateStore and applying changes directly in it through the `put` method events shoudl always pick up the updated state.
One thing i'm still wondering: what if I have a continuous high throughput of events.

**Could there still be a race condition between the puts we do on the KTable's KV store and the writes that are done in the KTable's topic ?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `KTable` is sharded into multiple physical stores and each store is only updated by a single thread. Thus, the scenario you describe cannot happen. If you have 2 records with the same timestamp that both update the same shard, they will be processed one after each other (in offset order). Thus, the second update will see the state of after the first update.

So maybe you just did describe your scenario not correctly?

**Update**

You cannot mutate the state when doing a join. Thus, the expectation that

```
event1 joins with state A => state A mutated to state X
```

is wrong. Independent of any processing order, when `event1` joins with `state A`, it will access `state A` in read only mode and `state A` will not be modified.

Thus, when `event2` joins, it will see the same state as `event1`. For stream-table join, the table state is only updated when new data is read from the table-input-topic.

If you want to have a shared state that is updated from both inputs, you would need to build a custom solution using `transform()`:

```java
builder.addStore(..., "store-name");
builder.stream("table-topic").transform(..., "store-name"); // will not emit anything downstream
KStream result = builder.stream("stream-topic").transform(..., "store-name");
```

This will create one store that is shared by both processors and both can read/write as they wish. Thus, for the table-input you can just update the state without sending anything downstream, while for the stream-input you can do the join, update the state, and send a result downstream.

**Update 2**

With regard to the solution, there will be no race condition between the updates the `Transformer` applies to the state and records the `Transformer` processes after the state update. This part will be executed in a single thread, and records will be processed in offset-order from the input topic. Thus, it's ensured that a state update will be available to later records.

Comment: I added some logs to illustrate my issue. maybe it's more understandable ?

Comment: I am not 100% sure if I understand the log. You get two types of event? Are some for populating the table and the other for the stream (if yes, which are which)? Where do you log `Updated` and what does `-null-null` mean? Also note, in a stream-table join, the table state is only updated from the "table input topic" and the stream does only read from the table (it never updates the table).

Comment: I updated my issue hoping it makes things more clear. The Updated part logged right after the leftJoin. And yes i get multiple types of events. Everything is done in a Event Sourced fashion.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: What I meant by mutation is that my ValueJoiner is responsible for compiling the new state. I understand it doesn't mutate it right away but that's actually what I would like to do: read-mutate-write from/to my ktable in an atomic way. As I understand this you're creating a 3rd state but I need the data to end back in the `table-topic`. So maybe all I need is `builder.addStore(..., "table-topic"); builder.stream("stream-topic").transform(..., "table-topic");` with the transformer accessing `table-topic` to read from it ? Does that make sense ? I'm not familiar with the transform/process API

Comment: I think I could get something satifying. I'm not having the issue anymore. Now just wondering if there could be a rarer race condition hidden in there. I'd be glad to have your input on the question I added at the end of my update.

Comment: As mentioned, the ValueJoiner does not have write access. Your approach seems to be feasible (it' similar to my suggestion but actually better as you save some code). I updated my answer with regard to your last question.

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax can I achieve same atomic 'writes' to GlobalKTable? I have similar case with events and state updates, but state won't fit in a single kafka-message, so I'm considering a GlobalKTable

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "atomic writes"? A `GlobalKTable` is design to read a changelog topic, and apply updates record-by-record.