# How to align (delay processing) Kafka events from two topics (by inner property)? OR How to sequentially process events from two topics?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

## Why I need this:

I'm implementing a system to schedule VMs on cluster.
VMs request resources from the cluster, and it's my responsibility to schedule a given RAM and CPUs to one and only one VMs. I guess the only way to guarantee this is to process requests one by one.

### Schemas

Requests to create VM are published to the `requests` topic (above Timeline). Cluster state (used/total resources) is stored in `cluster` topic (below) as series of updates.
`@some-time` is like event timestamp.

`requests` and `cluster` topics are partitioned based on `cluster_id`, so requests to the same cluster will come in order and can be processed sequentially. I'm using Kafka Streams.

### The problem

In cases where an interval between requests is at least 50-100ms I'm fine.

BUT.
Let's say there are some consecutive (within a couple ms) requests to create VM

[image: requests only]

If I consume events from `requests` as a KStream and join them with `cluster` KTable, and publish new cluster state to `cluster` after scheduling a VM, then the second request won't see this updates, as it comes sooner, than cluster-update events (and reading the second request is faster than pushing cluster update and then consuming it).

[image]

### What I want

Every request sees the cluster updates by the previous request. Be it by delaying request processing or any some other way, this is what I want.

[image]

### How to accomplish this?

I hope Kafka already has a mechanism to do similar things, and you can point me to it!

And here are my guesses:

- add metadata to `requests` and `cluster` topics. Namely events in `cluster` will contain `last_request_id` – the last processed request.
  `last_request_id` will also be stored in thread-local variable and passed to the next request. Requests are enriched with `last_request_id` and forwarded to new `delayed-requests` topic.
  Then it might be possible to join `cluster` and `delayed-requests` on `last_request_id` and process.
- create pre-instance transient state-store (in-mem?) with data about clusters in given partition. Requests read and write to this store, as well as publish to the `cluster` topic – persistent storage. On start-up state-store initiates from `cluster` topic.

UPD

Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46220663/kstream-ktable-join-writing-to-the-ktable-how-to-sync-the-join-with-the-ktable), will try, hope this will work for me

Answer (score 0):

Using the DSL, it might not be possible what you want. I guess you could use the Processor API though: for this case you use two state stores, one for the "usage table" and the second to buffer "provision request".

Every time to process a "provision request" you mark the "usage table" as blocked (maybe using some special key). If a second "provision request" comes in and the table is "blocked" you buffer it in the "request buffer store". Each time you update the "usage table" you check if there is any buffered event in the "request buffer store" and process one request. If the request store is empty, you can "unblock" the table.